# How to connect to remote Mysql database from flutter

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, flutter, ssh, amazon-lightsail

I am building a mobile application using **Flutter**. previously  I have built the web version and hosted on the **AWS Lightsail**. So I have the **remote MYSQL database on the lightSail** , I have to connect to the database from the flutter application. To connect to the remote host I  have only SSH authentication.

SO **How I can connect to the remote MySQL database on AWS LIGHTSAIL using SSH from a flutter application**